# Characterization of entire functions satisfying $f_1^{2}-f_2^{2}=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I characterize entire functions $f_1,f_2$ satisfying $f_1^{2}-f_2^{2}=1$? I don't even see any approach I can make.

Comment: If $f_2^2+1$ has all zeros of even order, you can find $f_1$ that fits it.

Comment: For what it's worth $f_1(z)=\cosh z$ and $f_2(z)=\sinh z$ work.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I want to find all such functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $g = f_1 + f_2$. Then it follows that

$$ 1 = (f_1 + f_2)(f_1 - f_2) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad f_1 - f_2 = \frac{1}{g}. $$

In particular, $g$ is an entire function that has no zero, and hence we can write $g = \exp(h)$ for some entire function $h$. (see below) Then

$$ f_{1} = \frac{e^{h} + e^{-h}}{2} = \cosh(h), \quad f_{2} = \frac{e^{h} - e^{-h}}{2} = \sinh(h). $$

The converse direction is straightforward, so we have characterized all such entire functions.

**Comment.** For the claim, Weierstrass factorization theorem gives a one-line proof. A more elementary method is to consider

$$ h(z) = \int_{0}^{z} \frac{g'(\zeta)}{g(\zeta)} \, d\zeta + c, $$

where $c \in \Bbb{C}$ is chosen so that $e^{c} = g(0)$. Then

$$ \{ g e^{-h} \}' = g' e^{-h} - g (g'/g) e^{-h} = 0, \quad g(0)e^{-h(0)} = 1 $$

shows that $e^h = g$.

Comment: Great answer, especially the elementary method to show $e^h=g$ is very clever.

Comment: @adrija, Thank you! In fact, this is a standard way of creating a "logarithm" of a holomorphic function locally, but in this case it is defined globally.